# How to find the interval of definition for separable nonlinear first order ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a IVP of y(0) = 1 and have found the solution to the separable equation which is y(t) = `root(-2e^t(t - 1) -1)`. I now need to find the interval of definition but I don't really know what that is.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/7a4f6f4b03d7a843863b729319b09e4e

I'm referring to equation (2).

Comment: So is the interval of defintion (-infiniti, -1.67) U (0.768, infiniti)?